# Loading MySQLdb data with mixed data type into Numpy's ndarray

Tags: python, mysql, sql, numpy

I have a mySQL data that looks like this (output of SequelPro), the table is called 
`mytable`:

[image]

The overall structure of that SQL db looks like this:
[image]

What I want to do is to load the above table into numpy 2d array. 
This is the code I have:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import numpy as np

db = conn.connect(host = "somehost.ac.jp",
                 user = "gandalf",
                 passwd = "abcxxx",
                 db = "mygreatdb",
                 )
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = """
      SELECT * from %s
      """ %mdb.escape_string(tablename)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
num_rows = int(cursor.rowcount)



D = np.fromiter(results, count=num_rows, dtype=('c8,str,f,f,f,f,f,f'))
print D
```

However it gives this error:

```
    D = np.fromiter(results, count=num_rows, dtype=('c8,str,f,f,f,f,f,f'))
TypeError: a float is required
```

What's the right way to do it? The main problem to me seems that I'm not sure
how to construct the `dtype` properly. What are the numpy equivalent of SQLs (`char, mediumtext, float`)? Please advise.

Finally I want to get the np.array that look like this:

```
array([['101D','NONRBP', 2.829e-07,....,0.00030],
       ['115L','NONRBP', 2.5e-5,....,0.01772]])
```

Comment: I guess, the problem is with a NULL in one of the fleat columns. You will need to cast NULL values to float values before passing to `fromiter`.